# Comparing multiple models using the same explanatory variables

Tags: r, generalized-additive-model

Using `mgcv` I have made 5 models, each one using a subset of my data, defined by quantiles. The response/explanitory variables are the same in each case, but the deviance explained by each in each model differs, along with the P values.

Is there a clever way of comparing the contributions of each explanitory variable in each model? The best I've come up with is using portions of the output of `summary(GAMx)` to create a monstrous table with the `Δ Deviance explained`, `Δ AIC` and `P value` for each each model, with the rows being the smoothed and parametric variables.[image: monstrous table]

This is pretty ugly and hard to interpret. Are there any functions or packages in `R` that would allow a comparison of models - with enough detail to show the contributions of each variable?

Reproducible code:

```
 library(mgcv)
 set.seed(0)
 n<-200;sig2<-4
 x0 <- runif(n, 0, 1);x1 <- runif(n, 0, 1)
 x2 <- runif(n, 0, 1)
 y<-x0^2+x1*x2 +runif(n,-0.3,0.3)
 g1<-gam(y~s(x0,x1,x2))
 g2<-gam(y~s(x0,x1,x2))
 g3<-gam(y~s(x0,x1,x2))
 g4<-gam(y~s(x0,x1,x2))
 g5<-gam(y~s(x0,x1,x2))
```

All 5 models here will be the same, but that shouldn't actually matter.

Comment: Also, it would be good to provide a reproducible example

Comment: I thought this might be suited at 'stats' too, but seeing as I'm specifically looking for a way to do this in R, I thought I might just end up back here anyway!

Comment: @gisol: Welcome to stackexchange!  It's preferred to flag a question for migration rather than reposting. Just click the flag link and write the moderator a note.  Also, for borderline questions like this, the consensus usually is to leave it where it is and see if you get a response; if not, then ask to migrate.  But the community gets a say too; if enough people agree with David Robinson, it will get migrated without you having to do anything.  One more note; most of the same people who answer questions like this hang out at both places, so migrating usually doesn't help get more answers.

Comment: PS: Your sense that it belonged on SO because you're looking for an R-specific method and not statistical expertise is exactly the right rubric to decide where a question goes.  Given that, I agree with you that SO is the right place, but again, we'll see what the community thinks; either place is fine for a question like this.

Comment: @gisol: Have you tried `anova(g1, g2, g3, g4, g5)`? (I just want to see if that's the kind of output you want)

Comment: I have tried anova(), but it's not the kind of comparison I want to make. My data is on the drivers of deforestation - I want to be able to show the contribution of each variable for each model - i.e. which variable is the biggest driver of deforestation for that subset of data (good forest, bad forest, terrible forest etc). So it's less a comparison of model performance, and more a comparison of the guts of the model.

Comment: @DavidRobinson `anova()` should rightly complain if the models were fitted to different data. The example here works because the data are the same in each model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just used a table in the end, with colours to make picking out high values easier. [image]

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I follow your quartile models but within each model set you can compare models using AIC wieght ($w_i$) for each model $i$:

$$
w_i = \frac{e^{(-0.5 * \Delta AIC_i)}}{\Sigma e^{(-0.5*\Delta AIC_i)}}
$$

which can be interpreted as the weight of evidence for each model.

If each variable is equally represented in the model set, we can also examine the relative importance of each variable by summing all the AIC wieghts for the models that contian variable $j$ where $j = 1,...,J$ variables.  Call this sum the "importance weight."  The ratio of imporance weights for two variables gives you an idea of how plausible a variable is.  For example, population density might have an importance weight of 0.9 and distance to forest edge might have an importance weight of 0.3.  Therefore, we could say population density is 3 times more plausible than distance to forest edge.